# Is it possible to connect multiple Buddypress sites?

Tags: social-networking, buddypress

I know very little about Buddypress but I am looking into it for a project at work.
I need to create a Social Network for a business that owns multiple companies. Then also create separate networks for each of these companies. Then I need all of these companies to be accessible through the "Mother" Network. For example the users of the "Mother" Network will need to see posts and comments from each of the other companies networks on their network. They will also need access to post on the other networks from the "Mother" network.

Please let me know if this is possible with Buddypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSON API for BuddyPress](https://github.com/tweichart/JSON-API-for-BuddyPress) and [BuddyPress API](https://github.com/boonebgorges/buddypress-api).

Or you can google about BuddyPress networks on the same install (there is a plugin for that - [BuddyPress Multi Network](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-multi-network/)).

Comment: Thanks mate I looked at BuddyPress Multi Network. I'm still figuring out if it can do what I need.